# Hibernate: How to use ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY()) in HQL

Tags: hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User implements Serializable{
    private String username; //Key

    // Getters and setters
}    

@Entity
@Table(name="POITable")
public class POI implements Serializable{
    private Integer id; //Key
    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="VisitedPlaceTable")
public class VisitedPlace implements Serializable{
    private Integer id; //Key
    private User user; //Many TO One relation
    private POI poi; //Many TO One relation

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**POITable**

```
===================
| id |    name    |
ــــــــــــ+ـــــ+
| 1  | poi name 1 |
-----+------------+
| 2  | poi name 2 |
===================
```

**VisitedPlaceTable**

```
=================================
| id |  user_username  | poi_id |
ــــــــ+ـــــــــــــــــ+ـــــ+
| 3  | xxxx@gmail.com  |   1    |
-----+-----------------+--------+
| 4  | xxxx@gmail.com  |   2    |
=================================
```

This native query

```
SELECT CONCAT('"',model.user_username,'","',**ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT visitedPlace.poi_id FROM VisitedPlaceTable visitedPlace WHERE visitedPlace.user_username = model.user_username),'|')**,'"','') FROM TourismPOIVisited model  INNER join POITable poi on poi.id = model.poi_id WHERE model.user_username='xxxx@gmail.com' GROUP BY model.user_username
```

return this next result (TRUE and EXPECTED result :))

> "xxxx@gmail.com","1|2"

**BUT** in HQL

```
SELECT CONCAT('\"',model.user.username,'\",\"',ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT visitedPlace.poi.id FROM VisitedPlace visitedPlace WHERE visitedPlace.user.username = model.user.username),'|'),'\"','\n') FROM VisitedPlace model WHERE model.user.username='xxxx@gmail.com' GROUP BY model.user.username
```

it fires

> line 1:70: unexpected token: **SELECT**

So how can i do it in HQL using **ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY())** or any other equivalent function ?

Comment: HQL queries are written against the object model, not against the database schema.So post your Pojo and your main class so we can help

Comment: @Akshay Object models (Entities is first thing in question body) please read my question well, anyway i added both (models and schema) to make the question more clear :)